# new symbol for pointer in VC2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++/CLR, what does a hat character ^ do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-clr-what-does-a-hat-character-do)

Just tried VC2008 and created a Form application. this is piece of code generated by IDE

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
```

what these "^"? Today is first time from VC6 to VC2008. They are the replacement of "*"?

Comment: The hat means that this is a reference to a garbage-collected object. Here you go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-clr-what-does-a-hat-character-do