# What is ^ in object definition?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the caret mean in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)
>   [In C++/CLR, what does a hat character ^ do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-clr-what-does-a-hat-character-do)

I created my first Win form application in Visual Studio C++, and browsing through the code saw something that I cannot understand:

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
```

What is the meaning of `^` sign in this line? I understand `*` and `&` but never seen `^` in definition of an object.

Comment: It's a hat pointer. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/500580

Comment: This is due to the fact that a Windows Forms application is not a C++ program but a C++/CLI (C++ for .NET, if you like) program, which are two different languages (though quite related). If you know about this fact and indeed want to use C++/CLI, then get a good tutorial/book about C++/CLI, as the `^` thing is an essential concept. If not, then rather use some other GUI library for C++.

Comment: http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/7285/cface.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Have a look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) this is not just C++ but C++/CLI

> In C++/CLI the only type of pointer is the normal C++ pointer, and the .NET reference types are accessed through a "handle", with the new syntax ClassName^ instead of ClassName*. This new construct is especially helpful when managed and standard C++ code is mixed; it clarifies which objects are under .NET automatic garbage collection and which objects the programmer must remember to explicitly destroy.

Comment: +1 The only answer taking the probable chance into account that the OP isn't aware of the difference between C++ and C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2):

It designates a garbage collected pointer. The normal C++ version is `*` for pointers, C++/CLI uses `^` to differentiate between managed and unmanaged. It also uses a different keyword to allocate the memory.

```
int* plain_cpp = new int;
delete plain_cpp; // unmanaged

int^ cpp_cli = gcnew int;
// managed, no delete possible
```

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent to a pointer (*) in C++/CLI. One key difference is that it is garbage collected, since C++/CLI is managed.

Answer (score 0):

^ means it is a CLR type and not a C++ native type