# What does the ^ character mean when used in C++ declarations?

Tags: c++-cli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)
>   [In C++/CLR, what does a hat character ^ do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-clr-what-does-a-hat-character-do)

What does the **^** character mean in C++ when applied to the data type in a variable declaration, as in:

```
String^ input;
```

or

```
List<String^>^ phoneNumbers;
```

Comment: It means it's not C++, but a language invented by Microsoft with a confusingly similar syntax and name.

Comment: See Rob Walker's post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming a Microsoft-compiler, this is not from C++ but from Microsoft own C++ dialects called *C++/CLI*. It denotes a .NET-garbage collected object.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: @prazuber: Now it does, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

It's a managed pointer. Similar to *, but collected by the GC.

Oh yeah, and it only works in C++/CLI, obviously (your post was already tagged cli, but I feel the need to explicitly state this).