# Get string memory location C++/CLI

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have a method in a Windows Forms Application where I get the contents from a textbox and store in a string. I would like to get the memory location where the string is stored. In a console application, this works with `&stringData`. But I am not able to get the memory location in this case.

This is what the function looks like:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ myString = textBox1->Text;
    // Get memory location of myString
}
```

Comment: That's not C++ - it's a Microsoft abomination called Managed C++/CLI or some such - please tag appropriately and fix your title.

Comment: I have removed the "C++" tag from the post.

Comment: I've fixed your title for you now also.

Comment: This "abomination" adds a garbage collector to C++.  Pretty important to de-tune the traditional memory-think, a GC moves objects around when it collects garbage.  In other words, objects like String don't have a stable memory location anymore.  There are very few cases where you actually need the address, you gets lots of help from the framework to avoid it.  Nobody can see *why* you need it.  If you really, really need it then you can use the `pin_ptr<>` class to get one.

Answer (score 0):

The string `myString` is a managed object. [You can tell because you declared it with the `^` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-clr-what-does-a-hat-character-do). You can't retrieve a native pointer to managed objects simply by using the address-of operator (`&`).

Instead, you can use [`pin_ptr<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx). That will pin the object so that it cannot be moved by the garbage collector, as long as the `pin_ptr<>` is in scope.

```
pin_ptr<System::String> pin = &myString;
void* ptr = pin;
// do whatever you want with ptr here...
```

But assuming that the code in the question has not been oversimplified for the purposes of an example, I have no idea why you'd want to do that. Just create an unmanaged object in the first place, and then retrieve its address like you normally would with the `&` operator.

Comment: Please recommend pin_ptr<> instead.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for the correction! I wasn't even aware of its existence. Clearly my knowledge of C++/CLI is limited, I was just thinking of how I'd do it in C#.