# Passing by refference from C++\CLI to C++

Tags: .net, c++-cli, interop, native

I have a C++\CLI wrapper to a C++ API of a commercial program.
A certain wrapper function looks like this:

```
int ReleaseObject(WDataObject^ object) {
    return (m_api->ReleaseObject(object->m_object));
};
```

On the previous version of the API, the C++ side was:

```
m_api->ReleaseObject(const api:DataObject *object)
```

And in the current API version the function has changed to:

```
m_api->ReleaseObject(const api:DataObject *&object)
```

My knowledge on C++\CLI is none and my C++ knowledge is very basic, and I have no clue on how to modify the wrapper function to make it compile.

I'd like to know how to modify the wrapper c++\CLI function to pass the object by reference according to what the C++ API expects.

EDIT:

Error when compiling:

```
Error   3   error C2664: 'int api::Api::ReleaseObject(api::DataObject *&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'api::DataObject *' to 'api::DataObject *&' ...\pf_api_test - 15.2.2\libs\digapiwrapper15.1_64bit\digApiWrapper.h   851 1   digApiWrapper
```

EDIT 2:

```
    [SerializableAttribute]
        public ref class WDataObject {
            public:

            api::DataObject* m_object;

            WApi^ t_api;

            String^  Name;
            int  Class;
            String^ key;

            WDataObject(api::DataObject* obj) { m_object = obj; };

            ~WDataObject();

 /*HERE GOES ALL THE FUNCTIONS WHICH I'M NOT SURE IF THEY ARE RELEVANT*/
    }
```

Comment: Does it *not* compile now, or are you just guessing? If so, specify the *exact* error.

Comment: It does not compile now, see the edit.

Comment: Anyone can explain me what is `^` in : `WDataObject^` ?

Comment: @MoKaT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-cli-what-does-the-hat-character-do

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera can you show you declaration of `WDataObject`? I don't know that we have enough information without it.

Comment: added the beginning of the definition in an edit, if more is needed I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a pointer to your `m_object` variable.  You did not quote the compiler error message, but it is somewhat guessable, it will not allow you to pass a pointer to a member of a managed class.  That tends to end very poorly when the garbage collector moves the object while the native code is executing.

You *must* create a stable pointer reference, the simplest way to do so is by copying the pointer to a local variable.  Like this:

```
int ReleaseObject(WDataObject^ object) {
    api:DataObject* arg = object->m_object;
    int retval = m_api->ReleaseObject(&arg);
    object->m_object = arg;
    return retval;
}
```

Which also fixes a likely bug in your original code, you probably should have set m_object to NULL yourself so you don't release it again.  Be sure to check for NULL in your destructor and finalizer and don't call ReleaseObject() again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work yet. on [api:DataObject* arg = object->m_object;] the error is [ an ordinary pointer to a C++/CLI ref class or interface class is not allowed] and in [int retval = m_api->ReleaseObject(&arg);] the error is [initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue]. I believe it has to do with the fact that * is for C++ and not for C++\CLI.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I got the answer of Hans Passant to work:

```
int ReleaseObject(WDataObject^ object) {
    //Before: return (m_api->ReleaseObject(object->m_object));
    api::DataObject* obj = object->m_object;
    int val = m_api->ReleaseObject(obj);
    object->m_object = obj;
    return val;
};
```

I'll give his answer as correct.