# correct usage of ^ in managed C++

Tags: c++-cli

I'm currently working on a C++ application. I came across this operator: `^`

In my case it's *not the XOR* I guess, because in the given code the usage is like that:

as a variable declaration:

```
Dictionary<System::String^, List<int>^>^ Tomatoes;
```

or as a Method returning parameter:

```
Food::Vegetable^ Vegetable_Create(List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<System::String^, float>^>>^ a, List<KeyValuePair<System::String^, Food::Cucumber^>>^ b, Dictionary<System::String^, float>^ c);
```

I was wondering what the `^` operator is actually used for.

Do you know what the `^` operator is used for in C++ and is it really necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: Also possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-cli-what-does-the-hat-character-do

Comment: @Tas I've voted to close this (500580) as dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli) (202463). Please help me ;)

Comment: It stands for a managed pointer in CLI. An abomination in other words. The first version of the CLI retained `*` and a `gc_new` family of functions to create managed objects. Why they didn't plump for a smart pointer class instead rather than fiddling around with language thereby risking compatibility breaks with future C++ standards is quite beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` operator in C++/CLI denotes a managed pointer. So `int*` is a raw pointer to an integer, while `System::String^` is a managed pointer to a CLI string.

All .Net classes must be handled via managed pointers or managed references (the `%` operator I think). So yes, it is absolutely necessary. It is, in fact, one of the most fundamental parts of C++/CLI. It is not part of normal C++.